# Don't Dagger broke an encapsulation principle?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

On the one hand, DI (in my case it is Dagger2) is a helpful/useful tool, however, on the other hand, I just can't stop thinking that it broke the incapsulating principle and I don't know how to live with that:)

Example:

Old-school approach

```
class A(private val objectB: B)
```

So here the object B has a private access modifier, which means that anyone who is going to use object A, has no access to the object B (nor set either get)

Dagger example

```
class A {
    @Inject lateinit var objectB: B
}
```

So now everyone who is going to use object A has a direct access to B (get and set)

What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't know Dagger specifically, but DI in general doesn't require properties to be public. There are DI frameworks which inject through the constructor or access private fields thought reflection. Dagger may have some limitations as I believe it is compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are [welcome to use your "old-school approach" with Dagger/Hilt](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#define-bindings) through constructor injection.

```kotlin
class A @Inject constructor(private val objectB: B)
```

See also:

- https://bloggie.io/@_junrong/dagger-2-for-android-part-v-inject-for-constructor-injection
- https://www.daniweb.com/programming/mobile-development/tutorials/536261/dagger-2-constructor-dependency-injection-in-kotlin
- https://www.folkstalk.com/tech/dagger-2-constructor-injection-in-kotlin-with-named-arguments-with-examples/

Comment: oh, ok, so in this case looks like Hilt kind of help to extend this functionality of DI and make it possible to inject in private fields, right?

Comment: @Sirop4ik: AFAIK this is part of Dagger itself. Beyond the three posts and the documentation that I linked to, you can search `dagger constructor injection kotlin` on major search engines to find additional resources.